# Are there any real-world case studies on the ASP.NET Dynamic Data Framework (DDF)?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data, customization, asp.net-dynamic-data, user-customization

I just wrapped up an arch review and next-gen recommendation for a client of ours that needs about the deepest level of customization I’ve ever seen for an application. Their desire is to customize their enterprise web application from the UI to the back-end **by customer** (40+ customers needing control-level customization). The customization will even include special business rules engines and very complex logic involving the transportation industry. As much as is possible, they want developer nirvana by automating everything so customizations can be driven by their customers and have minimal to no involvement by their devs.

Based on my research, though there will need to be some additional plumbing built in as well as security, the DDF will get them closer to their goals more than anything else out there. However, they're requesting more detailed information than what I provided for them.

I really need a case-study or some other such testimony of an enterprise-level company that has successfully implemented the DDF and gives details as to the enterprise problems it solved for them. Any direction or help would very much be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well at least one word of caution.  One important aspect (and selling point) of DDF is the assignment of metadata attributes to help scaffold columns and tables and the use of new dynamic data controls to gain advantage of that metadata (like QueryableFilterUserControl or DynamicDataManager or PageAction).  One aspect of metadata however is that it is assigned at run time, and cannot be manipulated once the application has started.  Therefore different users would all be logging into basically the same metadata set, and customization based on user would be a nightmare.  You can certainly set security and permissions based on group roles, but control level customization would be difficult.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is now July, your question is probably OBE by now. However, I have designed and fielded a transportation scheduling web app (ASP.Net 4.0) currently in use by 15 facilities within the Army and Air Force using Dynamic Data. This is a single instance, scalable web appplication adapting to customer requirements through database resident configuration settings. I extended the field templates to use Telerik ASP.Net controls and be configurable by user role and facility.

I have found little in the metadata that was much of a hindrance in providing a flexible configurable UI.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like a lot of Dynamic Data kungfu. Any good references you'd recommend?